# Esconder Botões

Tags: ionic, angular

Queria uma ajuda com angular, eu uso um ngFor para gerar os botões "-" e "+" que são os botões que dão escolha ao usuário. Dai na hora de escolher as opções tais como o sabor da pizza queria que quando ele clicasse em algum sabor esse botão "+" sumisse.. entende ?

```
<ion-list *ngIf="varia.eMax > 1">
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of itensVaria">
    <ion-item class="compact" *ngIf="item.idPV == varia.idPV">
      <ion-row no-padding>
        <ion-col col-7 style="text-align: left;">
          <h2 class="h2">Descrião do item</h2>

        </ion-col>

        <ion-col col-5>
          <button ion-button icon-only clear color="danger" (click)="changeQty(item, varia, -1)">
            <ion-icon name="remove-circle"></ion-icon>
          </button>

          <!-- <button ion-button clear color="danger"> qtd do item </button> -->

          <button ion-button icon-only clear color="danger" (click)="changeQty(item, varia, 1)">
            <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
          </button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>

    </ion-item>
</ng-container>
```

Mas como são vários sabores e o usuário pode escolher apenas no máximo 3 e no mínimo 2 por exemplo eu queria que ao clicar em x sabor o botão referente a este sabor ficasse indisponível indicando que ele ja clicou neste sabor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria possível você ter uma variável com os sabores adicionados.:

```
saboresAdicionados = [];
```

E colocar no botão um disabled chamnando um método saborJaAdicionado(item)

```
<button ion-button [disabled]="saborJaAdicionado(item)" icon-only clear color="danger" (click)="changeQty(item, varia, 1)">
 <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

O método poderia ser da seguinte forma:

```
saborJaAdicionado(item){
    let achouItem = false;
    this.saboresAdicionados.foreach(e => { 
       if (e === item) achouItem = true;
    }
    return achouItem;
}
```

Dessa forma para cada item ele vai testar se o sabor já está adicionado e fará a liberação/bloqueio do sabor.

Comment: Editei a pergunta dessa forma ai sei fazer, mas some com todos quero que faça conforme o item!

Comment: @SIGAutomação atualizei a resposta

Comment: Não deu certo. da um erro 
`Typescript Error
Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'any[]'.`

Comment: @SIGAutomação passei o código errado, sorry. O includes é só pra string

Comment: @SIGAutomação postei o certo ç.ç

Comment: Obrigado ficou muito bom.... agora como faço para mostrar a quantidade referida entre um botão e outro ?

Comment: @SIGAutomação desculpa, não entendi o que você quis dizer com a quantidade referida.

Comment: Exemplo: quando eu clico no botão ele adiciona o item né? Daí queria que ele mostrasse a quantidade de cada item entre um botão e outro. no meu código acima tem uma parte comentada entre os dois botões!

Comment: Vai poder adicionar + que uma vez o mesmo item?

Comment: sim............

Comment: @SIGAutomação se tiver como abre uma outra questão postando o código da tua  função changeQty que fica mais fácil

Comment: ai esta o link da pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/318728/mostar-quantidades-escolhidas